# Are multiple <meta> tags required or do I only need one?

Tags: html

I'm pretty new to coding and I wanted to try out creating a website on my own. I'm just not too sure about how to use meta tags. Can I put all the attributes I want to use in one tag, are multiple required or does the amount depend on which attributes I plan to use?

I've read a little of the documentation here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element, and a couple questions on this site but I still don't have a clear understanding of how many to use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="standard-theme.css" />
</head>
```

I just want a clear understanding of how many meta tags should be used in my document. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many you use it up to you. None are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Meta tags describe the meta of your page**

It tells the browser, screen readers and search engines how to interpret your page, what kind of information to expect and how it should work on mobile phones, among other things.

Mozilla has some good documentation about the [<meta />](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) tag. Have a lookt at the possible properties and their values to get a better understanding.

**Some interesting things to note:**

- Multiple meta tags can be used.
- The `charset` property declares the character encoding of the page
- The `name` property can be used together with the `content` property.

Each meta tag describes a separate meta property of the page. Most meta properties are identified by the `name=<propertyName>` part, which you can NOT pass multiple times.

**Common examples:**

- `<meta charset="utf-8" />`
- `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />`
- `<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />`
- `<meta name="description" content="This page contains information about X and Y" />`

Comment: Can I write `<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />`, instead of writing `<meta charset="utf-8" />` **and** `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />`

Comment: No, each meta tag describes a separate meta property of the page. Most meta properties are identified by the `name=<propertyName>` part, which you can't pass multiple times. They are also much easier to read if they are one per line.

Comment: Thank you! I think if you include this comment in your answer, it will be more complete.

Comment: Great idea. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

`<meta>` tag gives the specific information about the html document. You have to use multiple tags describe each metadata you use in the document depending on the requirement.
ex: page description, keywords, author of the document, last modified, etc

`<meta>` has multiple uses and you can find more information on W3Schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)